# Render frame from ISO file

Tags: video, decode, h.264, mpeg, decoder

I have a video_file.mp4 and I know that the **mdat** atom contains H.264 frames. Also I have a H.264 codec lib in my project. So, am I right that if I put **mdat** raw data into my lib's byte * decode(byte * data, int timeMsec) method I'll get a decoded frame? Or I need additional operations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two common H.264 bitstream packing formats.
1. Annex B
2. MP4.
For MP4 the packing mode is different and usually decoders prefer Annex B but not always.
MP4 is length prefixed and Annex B contains start codes. Some MP4 unwrappers will convert the bitstream to Annex B but not all.
Outside of the different packing formats – if your mp4 file contains any other streams – like – audio – your entire approach is not going work. The mdat box contains all streams interleaved.